# Django Picklist Won't Take Decimal Value

Tags: python, django, decimal, picklist

I am trying to get a simple django app to fill a form with a decimal field pick-list. The admin form displays it properly (selecting the right item from the list), but submitting gives an error:

```
'Select a valid choice. 1.046 is not one of the available choices.'
```

My model looks like this:

```
    GRAVITY_CHOICES = (
    (1.041, '1.041'),
    (1.042, '1.042'),
    (1.043, '1.043'),
    (1.044, '1.044'),
    (1.045, '1.045'),
    (1.046, '1.046'),
    )
...
    OG = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=3, choices=GRAVITY_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
```

It works perfectly fine when I submit a decimal value with the field as a simple text input field, but the pick list will make things easier.

What am I missing?

Comment: oddly, it works through the development server, but not when running under apache. Does that help?

Comment: Actually, not quite. I had picked a whole integer in testing. The integers work, but not decimals. A bug perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% if this is the issue but you have single quotes wrapped around the values to the right, it might be trying to pass the values as strings instead of numbers. Try removing the quotes.

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned that (I believe) I've tried all combinations of quotes, double-quotes, no quotes. But I'll try again. The admin form matches up the correct decimal value with the pick-list option.